# Qt5.12 : Calling qml callback function leads to sporadic segmentation faults

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a GridView where I'm calling a C++ method like this

```
function delegateDataHandler()
{
    print(Qt.formatTime(new Date(),"h:m:s:z"), "delegateDataHandler finished")
}

GridView.onAdd : {
    cppProxy.startObserver( itemDelegate.observerPointName, itemDelegate.delegateDataHandler );
}
```

Here is my cpp code :

```
void FacadeProxy::startObserver( QVariant observerName, QJSValue dataHandler )
{
   QString observerNameAsString = observerName.toString();

   try {
      m_facade->startObserver( observerNameAsString.toStdString(),
             [dataHandler, this]( std::vector<float> in ) mutable -> void {
                     if ( dataHandler.isCallable() ) {
                        QJSValue val = dataHandler.engine()->newObject();
                        val.setProperty("x", 10);
                        QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership( val.toQObject(), QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership);

                        QJSValueList args;
                        args.push_back( val );
                        dataHandler.call( args );

                     }
            }
      );
      Info("observer \"%s\" started", observerNameAsString.toStdString().c_str() );
   } catch(...) {
      Error("observer \"%s\" start failed", observerNameAsString.toStdString().c_str() );
   }
}
```

Sporadically I have a seg fault with `dataHandler.call( args );` Is there any obvious issue with this implementation?

Comment: Is it possible that the garbage collector has already deleted the delegateDataHandler when the lambda function is executed?

Comment: Im not sure actually, delegateDataHandler is a function from Item which is definitely not deleted while lambda is executing. Also I tried to save this handler as a private member of this c++ class but that did not help. So frustrated with this js engine ;(.

Comment: One thing you could try (I'm not sure it will help in this case), is to save the function handler as a property in qml and pass this to c++: `property var callbackFunction: delegateDataHandler`. This will avoid the function handler from being destructed before the qml object it is defined in, is being destructed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint - Ill give it a try.  I never got a crash when I call isCallable(). Only when I use call().